# Possible display names in Stack Exchange

Tags: support, profile-page, display-names

I'm member of Stack Overflow. My profile name is [`Abdulla`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4595675/abdulla).

A week ago I changed my name to `Moderator`. But after 2 days it changed back to `Abdulla`.

My questions are:

1. How did my name change?
2. And how it reversed my old name? (`Moderator` to `Abdulla`)
3. Can any one can see my recent names in a Stack Exchange site, besides me?

> **Note: Stack Exchange doesn't allow user to use any special characters only.**
>   [image: error]

Comment: My guess is that "Moderator" is a name confusing enough as to not being allowed as a user name.

Comment: The only missing thing is official warning you should have gotten. (Warning you from suspension if you do it again)

Comment: @ShadowWizard nothing came. Check it. And comment on next time.

Comment: I can't see your messages, and it is common sense that it is forbidden to pretend being moderator.

Comment: @Abdulla the whole point of common sense is that it does not have to be written.

Comment: Over on [Community Building](http://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com), we had this very question: [What should I do with a user pretending to be a moderator?](http://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/359/what-should-i-do-with-a-user-pretending-to-be-a-moderator). Answer: Ban them. Heed the warning you got from Martijn. Representing yourself as a moderator when you are not is playing with a ball of fire.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> How did my name change?

Probably a real moderator reacted to a flag. Pretending to be a site moderator is not allowed, and that is why the moderator diamond or lookalikes aren't allowed in your screen name.

> Can any one can see my recent names in a Stack Exchange site, besides me?

Moderators can, and from comment history we can probably see some names you have previously used. The list of previous names isn't publicly available though.

Answer (score 28):

A Stack Overflow moderator reverted your name back to the preceding name when we became aware you had changed it.

Impersonating a moderator is not allowed; your profile *About Me* section shows that you hoped people would be confused by your display name:

> Oops I'm not Moderator, I'm Just a User ;)

so we assumed you knew you were sailing close to the wind here and did not send you a moderator message telling you so. Let me assure you that if you did anything like this again we won't hesitate to send you a mod message.

The *Recent Names* list in your profile is only visible to you and to moderators; it holds names you used in the past 90 days. Moderators also have access to a separate history log that includes *all* name changes. This information is otherwise not visible to anyone else.